# How to load cached content using Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how to use Combine and want to use it to load cached content in the small example below.

Basically my problem is trying to achieve 2b in the below pseudo code.

> Step 1: Go to cache and check for cached content
>   Step 2a: If nothing in the cache -> Fetch stuff from the api client -> Cache content -> Return fetched content publisher
>   Step 2b: If cached content -> Return cached content publisher

The code below works, but of course produce the warning `⚠️ Will never be executed` on `fatalError()` since `Just` can never produce an error.

This was just the best solution I could come up with to make the compiler happy.
What Combine-functionality should be used in this case?

```
public func trainStationsPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<[TrainStation], Error> {
    // Create cache publisher
    let cachePublisher = loadTrainStationsFromCache()

    // Create publisher to fetch train stations from API client (map to new object) and update cache.
    let apiPublisher = apiClient.trainStationsPublisher()
        .map { $0.compactMap(TrainStation.init) }
        .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { (trainStations) in
            self.cachedTrainStations = trainStations
        })

    // Check the cache and return the result if it exists, otherwise fetch data from the api client.
    return cachePublisher
        .append(apiPublisher)
        .first()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

public func loadTrainStationsFromCache() -> AnyPublisher<[TrainStation], Error> {
    return Deferred<AnyPublisher<[TrainStation], Error>> { () -> AnyPublisher<[TrainStation], Error> in
        if let stations = self.cachedTrainStations {

            // This is the best I've managed to come up with.
            // Just mapping a non-existent error in order to get the desired return type. 
            // Note: fatalError() will never ever be executed since Just(stations) will never fail.
            // How am I suppose to return the cached stations in a publisher?

            return Just(stations).mapError { _ -> Error in
                fatalError()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } else {
            return Empty<[TrainStation], Error>().eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: I would use a [`Future`](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#reference-future) publisher.  You can use a closure that checks the cache and initiates the api request if necessary

Comment: Something like this, or would you suggest to wrap everything in `trainStationsPublisher` in a single `Future`?
`func loadFromCache() -> AnyPublisher<[TrainStation], Error> {
        Future<[TrainStation], Error> { promise in
            guard let trainStations = self.cachedTrainStations else {
                return promise(.success([]))
            }
            promise(.success(trainStations))
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }`